# Tagmanager script to store GCLID and MSCLKID for Hubspot contacts

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I figured out how to store and capture the GCLID using the code below in Tagmanager for updating contacts in Hubspot. However, I still need code to do the same thing for the MSCLKID (Microsoft Click ID for Microsoft Ads). If you know how to fix this problem, please paste the code for tagmanager in the reply that stores both. I would like to combine them into one script if possible.

If you need help with storing just the GCLID, paste the code below into tagmanager using all pages as the trigger.

```
<script>


function getParam(p) {
var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function getExpiryRecord(value) {
var expiryPeriod = 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 90 day expiry in milliseconds

var expiryDate = new Date().getTime() + expiryPeriod;
return {
value: value,
expiryDate: expiryDate
};
}

function addGclid() {
var gclidParam = getParam('gclid');
var gclidFormFields = ['gclid_field', 'foobar']; // all possible gclid form field ids here
var gclidRecord = null;
var currGclidFormField;

var gclsrcParam = getParam('gclsrc');
var isGclsrcValid = !gclsrcParam || gclsrcParam.indexOf('aw') !== -1;

gclidFormFields.forEach(function (field) {
if (document.getElementById(field)) {
currGclidFormField = document.getElementById(field);
}
});

if (gclidParam && isGclsrcValid) {
gclidRecord = getExpiryRecord(gclidParam);
localStorage.setItem('gclid', JSON.stringify(gclidRecord));
}

var gclid = gclidRecord || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gclid'));
var isGclidValid = gclid && new Date().getTime() < gclid.expiryDate;

if (currGclidFormField && isGclidValid) {
currGclidFormField.value = gclid.value;
}
}

window.addEventListener('load', addGclid);

</script>
```

You will also have to create a property in Hubspot called gclid, add it to your forms, and change it to hidden. Thanks in advance for your help!

Not a programmer yet. I pretty much just copy and paste code, and I'm not easily finding any solutions since Microsoft Ads seems to get less attention than Google Ads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a developer either but it would be easy to clone this into a different GTM tag and just find/replace gclid with msclkid everywhere. Also Gclid with Msclkid. Also gclsrc with msclsrc.

Then link to the same all page views trigger. Then create the hubspot property called msclkid, add it to forms as hidden and you're done.